# Handling minion keys with salt + vagrant

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack

I am currently looking into using salt to provision development virtualboxes for some of our project repositories. I'm labouring under the assumption that we will be setting up a salt-master server at some stage, as we are likely to want to use salt to provision the deployment boxes as well.

However I'm struggling to get my head around how to handle minion keys- let's say I have a project repo `MyRepo` which is a simple webservice that I want to be able to `vagrant up` and have running locally very quickly.

Now, most resources I've found online say that I should go onto my salt-master server, run `salt-key --gen-keys=my-repo` to generate the keys, then copy them into my project repo along with `minion.conf`, so the structure is similar to:-

```
|--MyRepo/
   |-- salt/
      |-- minion.conf
      |-- keys/
         |-- my-repo-pem
         |-- my-repo.pub
```

Fine, except now my repository contains the keys, and some of our stuff may be opened sourced, so with this system either we maintain two repos (stupid) or commit the keys to the repo (stupid?).

The idea I came up with next is instead of making the minion keys for each project, just have each developer create their own minion keys under their name e.g. `ptinkler`, and then `scp` them to their local `home_dir` under a `.salt/` folder or similar, probably renaming them to `minion.pem` and `minion.pub` in the process so that they can be referenced in the `VagrantFile` like so-

```
home_dir = ENV['HOME']

config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
  salt.verbose = true
  salt.minion_config = "#{home_dir}/.salt/minion.conf"
  salt.minion_key = "#{home_dir}/.salt/keys/minion.pem"
  salt.minion_pub = "#{home_dir}/.salt/keys/minion.pub"
  salt.run_highstate = true
end
```

Fine, a bit sloppy though, and I don't like having to rename them.

Next idea is to have a private git repo that contains the keys to all the projects, and developers just pull that repo down then symlink the correct folder into the project repo when needed. This also seems a bit weird. It also means that on any open source projects, people who pull the repo down can't use salt to provision anyway if they wanted to use Vagrant to get it running quickly.

I'm basically at a bit of a crossroads as to whether I stop trying to use salt-master and just set our repo's up to be masterless (I don't know how this will effect the difficulty when it comes to deploying them with salt?) or whether there is a way to configure it to keep everyone happy.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to use SaltStack to provision local Vagrant guests I would suggest you run Salt in masterless mode for the provisioning. How else would a third party use your repository without having access to your salt master? How would a developer test out different versions of salt states if the master wasn't local to his machine?

You could have a multi-machine vagrant environment and run a dedicated salt-master machine. But what you should aim for is having your development environment being as contained as possilbe - this goes along with ["The Tao of Vagrant."](http://mitchellh.com/the-tao-of-vagrant)

It shouldn't be too difficult to take the salt states you use for a master/minion deployment and adapt those to use in a masterless Vagrant setup. I recommend you go down that path. Two solid resources for getting started down this path -

- [Salt Masterless Quick Start](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html) from the SaltStack Documentation
- The [Vagrant Salt Provisioner Documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/salt.html)